# I can't add a record from the django form into a database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have this function in views.py file that responsible for adding a record into the Database

```
def add_academy(request,pk):
    child = get_object_or_404(Child_detail, pk=pk)
    academic = Academic.objects.get(Student_name=child)
    form = AcademicForm(request.POST, instance=academic)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('more',pk=pk) #it will redirect but can't create a new record
    else:
        form=AcademicForm()
    context = {
        'academic':academic,
        'child':child,
        'form':form,
    }

    return render(request,'functionality/more/academy/add.html',context)
```

And here is my form.py file

```
class AcademicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Academic
        fields='Class','Date','Average_grade','Overall_position','Total_number_in_class'
        labels={
            'Average_grade':'Average Grade',
            'Overall_position':'Overall Position',
            'Total_number_in_class':'Total Number In Class'
        }

    Date = forms.DateField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(     
        attrs={'type': 'date'} 
    )
        )
```

And here is my model.py file

```
class Academic(models.Model):
    Student_name = models.ForeignKey(Child_detail,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Class = models.CharField(max_length =  50)
    Date = models.DateField()
    Average_grade = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    Overall_position = models.IntegerField()
    Total_number_in_class = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Student_name)
```

And also this is my template will be used to display form

```
 <div class="card-body">
            <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              {{form | crispy}}
              <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is passing the `if form.is_valid()` check?

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting a new record to be created, you can't pass `instance` into the form.

```
child = get_object_or_404(Child_detail, pk=pk)
form = AcademicForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.Student_name = child
    form.save()
```

Comment: if i don't pass an instance it raise  integrity error

Comment: @RegnaldTerry I've updated my answer. I'm guessing the validation error was stating that `Student_name` can't be null. If you set that after checking if the form submission is valid, it should create a new instance as desired.

Answer (score 0):

to add new record

```
def add_academy(request,pk):
    child = get_object_or_404(Child_detail, pk=pk)
    academic = Academic.objects.get(Student_name=child)
    if request.method=='POST':
    form = AcademicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('more',pk=pk) 
        else:
            context = {
             'academic': academic,
             'child': child,
             'form': form,
         }
            return render(request, 'functionality/more/academy/add.html',context)
    else:
        form=AcademicForm()
        context = {'academic':academic,'child':child,'form':form}

        return render(request,'functionality/more/academy/add.html',context)
```