# HOW TO EDIT A RECORD BY USE DJANGO FORM INTO A TEMPLATE

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two models that have relationship to each other which are a ***child*** and ***academy*** model which means that a child can have academic details,and then i pass a child ID into the template to edit academic details of child

here is academy model

```
#ACADEMY MODEL
from child.models import Child_detail
class Academic(models.Model):
    Student_name = models.ForeignKey(Child_detail,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Average_grade = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    Overall_position = models.IntegerField()
    Total_number_in_class = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Student_name)
```

here is child model

```
#CHILD MODEL
from django.db import models

class Child_detail(models.Model):
    Firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Tribe = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Current_Address = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Firstname
```

I come to the scenario that i want to edit academic details of a child by use django form to the template that i pass child ID

```
def edit(request,pk):
    child=get_object_or_404(Child_detail,pk=pk)
    form=AcademicForm(request.POST or None,instance=child)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.Student_name=child
        form.save()
        return redirect('more',pk=pk)
    context={
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request,'functionality/more/academy/edit.html',context)
```

And here is my form.py file

```
class AcademicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Academic
        fields='Class','Date','Average_grade','Overall_position','Total_number_in_class'
        labels={
            'Average_grade':'Average Grade',
            'Overall_position':'Overall Position',
            'Total_number_in_class':'Total Number In Class'
        }

    Date = forms.DateField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(     
        attrs={'type': 'date'} 
    )
        )
```

And also this is my template that pass child id

```
            <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              {{form}}
              <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            </form>
```

Comment: You use an `AcademicForm` for a `Child_detail` model?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60953998/i-cant-add-a-record-from-the-django-form-into-a-database and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958412/how-to-create-data-into-the-database-with-django-form

Comment: That is not a duplicate questions Sir

Answer (score 0):

> after validation of form

```
if form.is_valid(): 
      form.Student_name=child
      form.save()
```